# Il y a-t-il une différence entre "nous nous sommes manqués" et "nous nous sommes manqué"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, accord, conjugaison, complément-cod

En faisant des recherches sur l'accord des **verbes pronominaux aux temps du passé avec le COD devant**, j'ai rencontré cet article: https://www.rtl.fr/culture/arts-spectacles/ecrit-on-vous-nous-avez-manque-ou-vous-nous-avez-manques-7800895884

Cela me dit que les deux phrases "Vous nous avez manqué" et "Vous nous avez manqués" sont toutes les deux correctes mais avec de différentes structures / différents sens:

*dans la première partie du message : "Vous nous avez manqué", vous avez manqué "à qui" : complément d’objet indirect, donc pas d’accord !*
*dans un autre sens, comme dans : "Vous êtes passés chez nous alors que nous venions de sortir : vous nous avez manquéS" (vous avez manqué qui, nous, COD placé avant, on accorde) Les merveilles du participe passé !*

Mais alors quand je regarde la conjugaison de "se manquer" sur la conjugaison l'Obs( https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/se_manquer.php ), j'aperçois qu'il y a l'accord.

Je me suis donc demandé s'il y a-t-il une différence entre "nous nous sommes manqués" et "nous nous sommes manqué"? Et que si ces deux veulent dire respectivement "nous avons manqué nous-même" et "nous avons manqué à nous-même"?

-->Je remercie la personne qui aura la patience de lire tout ce que j'ai écrit.

Comment: Sous réserve de validation par des grammairiens authentiques : « — Durant toute cette période, nous nous sommes *manqué*.  » chacun de nous a ressenti l'absence de l'autre comme un manque ; *nous* a manqué ***à** nous*. « — Oui, et pour finir, nous nous sommes *manqué**s*** à Istanbul. » au même moment, au même endroit, la rencontre n'a pas eu lieu, faute d'information ; *nous* a manqué *nous* à Istanbul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premier sens:
*manquer quelque chose ou quelqu'un* = le louper, le rater.
Il y a un **complément d'objet direct** .
Sa forme réciproque **se manquer** veut dire: *manquer qui? soi !*.

Avec ce sens on doit écrire:
*Nous nous sommes manq**ués*** (lors de notre rendez-vous de ce matin).
Au féminin on dirait:
*Elles se sont manqu**ées*** ( de peu à la sortie de l'école ).

Deuxième sens:
*Manquer **à** quelqu'un*
Le complément d'objet est indirect.
On écrira donc:
*Nous nous sommes man**qué*** (sous entendu: *les uns/nous **aux** autres/nous*)